# Php option value

Tags: php, html-select

I have a list of areas (1000+) and i was wondering if there was a way i can do this easier with code instead of repeating each value.

```
<select>
<option value="apple" <?php if ($user_data["$area"] == apple){echo 'selected';} ?>>Apple
</option> 

<option value="lemon" <?php if ($user_data["$area"] == lemon){echo 'selected';} ?>>Lemon
</option> 

<option value="orange" <?php if ($user_data["$area"] == orange){echo 'selected';} ?>>Orange
</option> 

<option value="banana" <?php if ($user_data["$area"] == banana){echo 'selected';} ?>>Banana
</option>
</select>
```

I.E. have the same piece of php code for each option instead of having to type in the name of the value each time

```
<?php if ($user_data["$area"] == option VALUE){echo 'selected';} ?>
```

Could you provide some code or ideas for what to look in tutorials, i have no idea how to start. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps a for loop iterating over an array of compiled elements you would like to render? Try compiling all of the option values into a 1 dimensional array and use a for loop to write each to the screen.

Comment: The examples below (with the exception of mine) will render out the same exact content you are writing by hand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
$areas = array(
    'apple' => 'Apple',
    'lemon' => 'Lemon',
    'orange' => 'Orange',
    'banana' => 'Banana'
);
```

Then use that array to print the select:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($areas as $value => $text): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php if ($user_data[$area] == $value) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $text; ?>
    </option> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I am using an associative array because I am assuming that you want to be able to customize the areas' text label, and that they will not only be a capitaized version of the value used to match the user data.

Comment: This is a good option, but I think its better not to wrap $area in quotes. $user_data[$area] is just fine, maybe even better than $user_data["$area"]. Using variables in double quotes is best used only to improve readability when adding multiple variables to a string, there's really no point for it to be used in this case.

Comment: yes it is, I just copied the code from the question... this comment should be directed at the OP ;)

Comment: @SirDarius Ah, I didn't even notice the OP had $area wrapped in quotes. Sorry about that. :P

Comment: my select name is "fruit", so when i do echo $_POST['fruit'], I have for example 'apple', but how can I have 'Apple' ? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
//pseudo
$arr = array("apple", "lemon", "orange", ...);
foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value;
    if($user_data[$area] === $value) {
        echo 'selected';
    }
    //echo {the end of your option field syntax}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All the solutions look good... Here's one more way though:

```
<select>
<?php
  $areas = array('apple', 'lemon', 'orange', 'banana');
  $areas_count = count($areas);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $areas_count; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $areas[$i] . '"';
    echo ($user_data[$area] == $areas[$i]) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo '>' . ucwords($areas[$i]) . '</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($areas as $key => $val)
{
    $select.= '<option '; // opening the option tag
    foreach ($selected_from_db as $keyselected => $valselected)
    {
      $val_fetch_from_array = $valselected == $val['campaignid'] ? 'selected' : '';
      $select.= $val_fetch_from_array; // codes for selecting multiple values
    }
    $select.= ' value = "' . $val['campaignid'] . '">#' . $val['campaignid'] . '-' . $val['campaignname'] . '</option>'; // closing the option tag
}
```