# Trying to create dynamic select boxes that contains same data

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create dynamic select boxes that contain the same data, however, only the first select box contains the data and not the others.

Can someone assist me as to how I would populate the others accordingly please.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<?php $i= 1; ?>
  <table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]"/></td>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td><select name="fireman[]"><option value=""></option><?php require("php/fireman_list.php"); ?></select> </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script language="javascript">
  function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("select");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "fireman[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);
  }

  function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try 
    {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
      {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) 
        {
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
    catch(e) 
    {
      alert(e);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing code for adding options in select tag. but first you need to have array of options value for populating it or use ajax call

Comment: The data that i'm trying to pull are from the database...so would it still be something along this line?:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884685/php-option-value) @wisdom

Answer (score 0):

Err... From what I understand of your code, I am not quite sure you're using the right tool for the job.

You have PHP on the server side that is meant to generate HTML pages, so why bother to do it in JavaScript? Even with the help of JQuery, adding DOM elements dynamically is a messy, verbose and tedious business.

If you want your page to display only part of its contents, the usual way of doing it is to have all the possible contents created on the page, and mask the parts that you don't want (using CSS attributes).

I assume you don't plan to allow to create on your page an infinite number of... Mmmm... whatever these dynamic table represent?

If you can set a limit to, say, 10 instances, you can create these 10 instances with a simple PHP loop (or even by copy-pasting the HTML code for a proof of concept test), and then replace your creation/destruction process with a show/hide mechanism.

Initially, only the first instance will be shown. the "Add" button will make the next one visible, and the "Delete" button will make the last one invisible.

If you index your table instances by Id (i.e. "DataTable_0", "DataTable_1", etc.), it is really easy to switch them on and off with CSS, like so:

```
function hide_table (table_number)
{
    document.getElementById ("DataTable_"+table_number).style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can make them reappear just as easily using `block` instead of `none` for display property.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, that wouldn't do because the user should able to enter up to 30 select boxes. And as it relates to removing the select boxes, the users should be able to select any of the select boxes they wish to remove, whether it's the first select box and/or the one in the middle. @kuroi neko

Comment: OK. 10 was just an example. PHP can generate 1000 tables if you ask it to. As for hiding/showing the elements, I just followed your sample code. As you can see, hiding the elements can be done in any order. Besides, setting `display` to `none` removes the element from the display just as if it had been destroyed (though it isn't :)). Really I think you should reconsider. You could make your current solution work eventually, but that is not the sensible thing to do, IMHO. Now wait for second opinions and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the **addRow** function so that it accepts two additional parameters which are arrays consists of the values and Text for options of the created select item.

**selValue**  will be the array of values of options in select and

**selText**  will be the array of Text of options in select

Let the code be:

```
function addRow(tableID, selValue, selText)
{
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.name="chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element2 = document.createElement("select");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "fireman[]";

  //dynamically adding data from arrays passed
  for(var i=0; i<selValue.length;i++)
  {
      op=document.createElement("option");
      op.text= selValue[i];
      op.value= selText[i];
      cell3.add(op);
  }
  // dynamic adding end
  cell3.appendChild(element2);
}
```