# Keep value for SELECT input after validation (Form - POST Method )

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

I'm trying to keep the value of my select input after validation by php but i can't get it to work.

This works for text input :

```
<input type="text"  name="answer" id="answer" 
 value="<?php if(isset($_POST['answer'])){ echo $_POST['answer'];}else{ echo '';} ?>">
```

But how to make this work for  input ?

```
<select name="question" value="<?php  ?>" >
                                <option value="one">Num 1 ?</option>
                                <option value="two">Num 2 ?</option>
                                <option value="three"> Num 3 ?</option>

                            </select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884685/php-option-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `selected` attribute:

```
<select name="question">
    <option value="one"<?php if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $_POST["question"] == "one") print(" selected")?>>Num 1 ?</option>
    <option value="two"<?php if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $_POST["question"] == "two") print(" selected")?>>Num 2 ?</option>
    <option value="three"<?php if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $_POST["question"] == "three") print(" selected")?>> Num 3 ?</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Select you need to do it this way

```
<select name="question" value="<?php  ?>" >
    <option value="one" <?php if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $_POST["question"]=="one"){ echo 'selected';} ?> >Num 1 ?</option>
    <option value="two">Num 2 ?</option>
    <option value="three"> Num 3 ?</option>

 </select>
```

But I would suggest to do it with JQuery which is much more simplified since this IF statement you will be have to write for every value